# Pure CSS tab panel not working

Tags: html, css

Just a background on what i intend to do. Currently i am trying to create a tab panel that run purely on css. When user click on first tab, it will show tab 1 content and so on for tab 2 and tab 3. On the tab panel, i also need a div wrap around the tabs.

The tabs are created using radio button. Currently when i wrap a div over the tabs, when i click on the tab, no content will show up, but if i remove the div wrap around the tab, it will work.

The desire outcome will be have an outer div wrap over all the tabs and content will display when tab are being clicked.

Here is the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/mathiasloy/hpdqhdw8/

```css
*, *:before, *:after {margin: 0; padding: 0; box-sizing: border-box;}
body {background: #2F2556; color: #B9B5C7; font: 14px 'Open Sans', sans-serif;}

/* You can safely remove the next two lines */
.top { padding-right: 20px; background: #261F41; text-align: right; }
a { color: rgba(255,255,255,0.6); text-transform: uppercase; text-decoration: none; line-height: 42px; }

h1 {padding: 100px 0; font-weight: 400; text-align: center;}
p {margin: 0 0 20px; line-height: 1.5;}

.main {margin: 0 auto; min-width: 100%; max-width: 100%;}
.content {background: #fff; color: #373737;}
.content > div {display: none; padding: 20px 25px 5px;}
.overall-nav {width: 100%; background-color: white; padding-left: 40px; padding-right: 40px; border-radius: 50px}
input {display: none;}
label {display: inline-block; padding: 15px 25px; font-weight: 600; text-align: center; width: 33%; border-radius: 50px }
label:hover {color: #fff; cursor: pointer;}
input:checked + label {background: #ed5a6a; color: #fff;}

#tab1:checked ~ .content #content1,
#tab2:checked ~ .content #content2,
#tab3:checked ~ .content #content3
{
    display: block;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 400px) { label {padding: 15px 10px;} }
```

```html
<div class="main">
 <div class="overall-nav">
  <input id="tab1" type="radio" name="tabs" checked>
  <label for="tab1">New York</label>

  <input id="tab2" type="radio" name="tabs">
  <label for="tab2">London</label>

  <input id="tab3" type="radio" name="tabs">
  <label for="tab3">Mumbai</label>
 </div>


 <div class="content">  
  <div id="content1">
   <p>
    New York – referred to as New York City or the City of New York to distinguish it from the State of New York, of which it is a part – is the most populous city in the United States and the center of the New York metropolitan area, the premier gateway for legal immigration to the United States and one of the most populous urban agglomerations in the world. A global power city, New York exerts a significant impact upon commerce, finance, media, art, fashion, research, technology, education, and entertainment.
    <p>
     Home to the headquarters of the United Nations, New York is an important center for international diplomacy and has been described as the cultural and financial capital of the world.
    </p>
   </div>

   <div id="content2">
    <p>
     London is the capital city of England and the United Kingdom. It is the most populous city in the United Kingdom, with a metropolitan area of over 13 million inhabitants. Standing on the River Thames, London has been a major settlement for two millennia, its history going back to its founding by the Romans, who named it Londinium.
    </p>
    <p>
     London's ancient core, the City of London, largely retains its 1.12-square-mile (2.9 km2) mediaeval boundaries and in 2011 had a resident population of 7,375, making it the smallest city in England. Since at least the 19th century, the term London has also referred to the metropolis developed around this core.
    </p>
   </div>

   <div id="content3">
    <p>
     Mumbai is the capital city of the Indian state of Maharashtra. It is the most populous city in India, most populous metropolitan area in India, and the eighth most populous city in the world, with an estimated city population of 18.4 million and metropolitan area population of 20.7 million as of 2011. Along with the urban areas, including the cities of Navi Mumbai, Thane, Bhiwandi, Kalyan, it is one of the most populous urban regions in the world.
    </p>
    <p>
     Mumbai lies on the west coast of India and has a deep natural harbour. In 2009, Mumbai was named an alpha world city. It is also the wealthiest city in India, and has the highest GDP of any city in South, West or Central Asia.
    </p>
   </div>

   <div id="content4">
    <p>
     Tokyo, officially Tokyo Metropolis, is one of the 47 prefectures of Japan. Tokyo is the capital of Japan, the center of the Greater Tokyo Area, and the most populous metropolitan area in the world. It is the seat of the Japanese government and the Imperial Palace, and the home of the Japanese Imperial Family.
    </p>
    <p>
     Tokyo is in the Kantō region on the southeastern side of the main island Honshu and includes the Izu Islands and Ogasawara Islands. Tokyo Metropolis was formed in 1943 from the merger of the former Tokyo Prefecture and the city of Tokyo.
    </p>
   </div>
  </div>

 </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```css
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background: #2F2556;
  color: #B9B5C7;
  font: 14px 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}


/* You can safely remove the next two lines */

.top {
  padding-right: 20px;
  background: #261F41;
  text-align: right;
}

a {
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: none;
  line-height: 42px;
}

h1 {
  padding: 100px 0;
  font-weight: 400;
  text-align: center;
}

p {
  margin: 0 0 20px;
  line-height: 1.5;
}

.main {
  margin: 0 auto;
  min-width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.content {
  background: #fff;
  color: #373737;
}

.content > div {
  display: none;
  padding: 20px 25px 5px;
}

.overall-nav {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: white;
  padding-left: 40px;
  padding-right: 40px;
  border-radius: 50px
}

input {
  display: none;
}
nav ul{
  float:left;
  width:100%;
}
.clear{
  clear:both;
}
nav li {
  float: left;
  width: 33.33%;
  border-radius: 50px;
  list-style: none;
}

nav li label {
  padding: 15px 25px;
  font-weight: 600;
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
}

nav li:hover {
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#tab1:checked ~ nav .tab1,
#tab2:checked ~ nav .tab2,
#tab3:checked ~ nav .tab3 {
  background: #ed5a6a;
  color: #fff;
}

#tab1:checked ~ .content .tab1,
#tab2:checked ~ .content .tab2,
#tab3:checked ~ .content .tab3 {
  display: block;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 400px) {
    label {
        padding: 15px 10px;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
   <input id="tab1" type="radio" name="tabs" checked="checked">    
   <input id="tab2" type="radio" name="tabs">   
   <input id="tab3" type="radio" name="tabs">    
   <nav>
      <ul>
         <li class="tab1">
            <label for="tab1">New York</label>
         </li>
         <li class="tab2">
            <label for="tab2">London</label>
         </li>
         <li class="tab3">
            <label for="tab3">Mumbai</label>
         </li>
      </ul>
      <div class="clear"></div>
   </nav>
   <div class="content">
      <div class="tab1">
         <p>
            New York – referred to as New York City or the City of New York to distinguish it from the State of New York, of which it is a part – is the most populous city in the United States and the center of the New York metropolitan area, the premier gateway for legal immigration to the United States and one of the most populous urban agglomerations in the world. A global power city, New York exerts a significant impact upon commerce, finance, media, art, fashion, research, technology, education, and entertainment.
         <p>
            Home to the headquarters of the United Nations, New York is an important center for international diplomacy and has been described as the cultural and financial capital of the world.
         </p>
      </div>
      <div class="tab2">
         <p>
            London is the capital city of England and the United Kingdom. It is the most populous city in the United Kingdom, with a metropolitan area of over 13 million inhabitants. Standing on the River Thames, London has been a major settlement for two millennia, its history going back to its founding by the Romans, who named it Londinium.
         </p>
         <p>
            London's ancient core, the City of London, largely retains its 1.12-square-mile (2.9 km2) mediaeval boundaries and in 2011 had a resident population of 7,375, making it the smallest city in England. Since at least the 19th century, the term London has also referred to the metropolis developed around this core.
         </p>
      </div>
      <div class="tab3">
         <p>
            Mumbai is the capital city of the Indian state of Maharashtra. It is the most populous city in India, most populous metropolitan area in India, and the eighth most populous city in the world, with an estimated city population of 18.4 million and metropolitan area population of 20.7 million as of 2011. Along with the urban areas, including the cities of Navi Mumbai, Thane, Bhiwandi, Kalyan, it is one of the most populous urban regions in the world.
         </p>
         <p>
            Mumbai lies on the west coast of India and has a deep natural harbour. In 2009, Mumbai was named an alpha world city. It is also the wealthiest city in India, and has the highest GDP of any city in South, West or Central Asia.
         </p>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: If i want the first tab to be on the same starting point as the nav, so the total width for all 3 tab is the same width as the nav width, how can i go about doing it. Currently i tried padding: 0px, but it is not working.

Comment: @mathiasloy now please check. I have updated css. Use `float:left` instead of `display:inline-block` and give `clear` class after `ul` tag for clearing float value.

Answer (score 1):

You need to pick up selectors in the tree that switch tabs. Since the tilde works with elements that are on the same level
https://codepen.io/ssstelllo/pen/wPMQyp

```
#tab2:checked ~ .content #content2,
```

Comment: Hi, may i know what do you meant by "pick up selectors in the tree that switch tabs". Since the tilde works with elements that are on the same level?